# Whirlpool refrigerator model ed22tqxgw

Tags: usa

The ice maker has no water going to it. Has never worked. Each day at 1am & 3am a clunking noise from the ice maker section. Owned since 1999, works great otherwise. What causes this noise & what to do to stop this.

Comment: You've gotten good usage—24 years!—out of that fridge.

Answer (score 2):

To stop the noise, from an icemaker that has been taking up space in your freezer and not making ice for 24 years? Should stop if you turn it off by lifting the wire bail:

[image: More precisely this model ice maker instructions]

Image source https://www.whirlpool.com/content/dam/global/documents/199906/use-and-care-guide-2194921.pdf

Preferably, or if it manages to make noise despite being turned off, remove the ice-maker. I would have done that 24 years ago...

Follow the first half of instructions to replace an ice maker, and then stop. Enjoy having some additional freezer space. Should be a matter of a few screws and unclipping some things and unplugging a wire harness. At this era it was an option, so it can be removed, unlike some of the newer refrigerators where it's non-optional and there really isn't a way to remove it, effectively (or you don't get the space back, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at the manual, there doesnt appear to be a way to turn it off.  You can lock it, but it it still runs.

My Samsung one is noisy and has a screw to push the ice forward.  Perhaps Whirlpool has a similar arrangement.  If so, it would rotate at a predetermined rate.